# Removing the column(s) from matrices in a fast way C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, intel, multiplication

Suppose that we have matrix `A (m*n)` stored in packed form (1-d array of size `m*n` - with leading dimension - columns). I need to get reduced matrices `A(S)` - which are resulted from deletion of 1 or more columns from `A`. I can easily to this by hand in the loops, but there is another approach - using selection matrices `I(S)` which are the identity matrices (all zeros but 1s on diagonal) with 1 or more column removed. Then, e.g. if I need to remove 3-rd row from `A`, I need to form `I(3)` - identity without 3rd column and then `A(3)=A*I(S)`. And since I'd need many variations of `A`, I would need all different identity matrices `I(S)` with different columns removed.

I'm thinking of this way because I use Intel Math Kernel Library - which is extremely efficient for matrix multiplications.

So the question is what do you think the fastest way of forming new matrix `A(S)`: by hand, directly working with `A` or first forming `I(S)` - and the question is how to quickly form these matrices - and then multiplying `A*I(S)` or you can suggest any other fast solution.

To illustrate suppose that we have the matrix `A`:

```
1 2 3 

4 5 6 

7 8 9
```

It is stored in array `A=[1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9]. Suppose I need to form`A(2)` that is remove 2nd column. I need to have on output:

```
1 3 

4 6 

7 9
```

which is stored in C++ as `A_S=[1,4,7,3,6,9]`. 
This can be done directly on matrix A, which would take `O(n^2)` time and not efficient for large matrices. Or we can form `I(2)`:

```
1 0

0 1

0 0
```

stored in c++ as `I_S = [1,0,0,0,1,0]`. Then `A(2) = A*I(2)`

Comment: Do you actually need a result of that specific matrix datatype (or otherwise need to modify the matrix)? Because otherwise it seems to me like the most efficient way to do this could be writing a `matrix_view` class, which acts like a normal matrix, but modifies the indices on access in order to omit the columns, as this would free you from actually performing a copy.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be careful to use `I` if you mean `identity matrix`. `Identity matrix` are generally square matrix, while you are using is usually not square matrix since you removed column(s) from the original matrix. Let me call the transformation matrix as `T`, instead of `I`.

Now I am trying to answer your question:

> the question is how to quickly form these matrices

so based on above assumption, `T(2)` should be:

```
1  0
0  0
0  1
```

since

```
1   2  3       1  0     1  3
4   5  6   *   0  0  =  4  6
7   8  9       0  1     7  9
```

You can compare the `T(2)` with original `I(3)` (here it is identity matrix) based on the situation that you are removing the second column.

```
      1  0  0
I(3)  0  1  0
      0  0  1
```

Since you know which column to remove, you will know the index range of the 1D array that you used to store `I(3)`, in this case, it is: `A_I(3) = [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]`; you know that index `[3,5]` are second column, you just need to remove those 3 values, you will get `T(2)` as in above example, which is `A_T(2) = [ 1 0 0 0 0 1]`. So the idea is that if you know which column of original matrix to remove, you just remove the values from  the 1D array that stores identity matrix within the  index range that the original column maps to. In this example, you remove values from `[3,5]` which `2nd` column of original matrix maps to.

Now you can use your Matrix library to multiply `A` and `A_T(2)` and get the result matrix.

Comment: Yeah, all that you wrote is pretty clear and I didn't have problem of understanding the math behind the issue. The question is how to quickly get an array `b=[1,4,7,3,6,9]` out of `a=[1,0,0,0,0,1]` using c++. 2 main issues are: time and space complexity. I aim matrices with possibly billions of elements

Comment: @user2028058 if you only need to get b when removing 2nd column, I think you can do it directly on the array since you know 2nd column to remove, then you need to remove entries with index values in [3,5], in this case it is 2,5,8. You don't even need a anymore I guess.

Comment: this is obvious brute-force way.. running loop m*n times and copying needed elements to b. Imagine doing this m*n operation for every permutation of removed columns of A..

Comment: @user2028058 I think you have to copy elements from a to b anyway, right? but if you know which elements are not belongs to b based on index values to remove, then you just loop through a and write to b, though the length of array a is always m*n. I am assuming that you always know which column to remove and always have a stored in 1D array.  That is pretty much I can think of, I am not expert in matrix operations anyway, sorry, not helpful.